# Is there a name for the anti-pattern of having low-level components controlling higher-level ones?

Tags: anti-patterns, code-smell, coding-style

For example, suppose I had a `pageControl` UI class and a `searcher` business logic class with the following :

pageControl.js

```
function searchButtonClicked() {
  // call business logic class method when button clicked
  searcher.beginSearch();
}

function showSearchResultsPage(searchResults) {
  // when this is called, display results
  ui.loadContent(searchResults);
}
```

searcher.js

```
// This module has a low to moderate chance of someday being used on two or more different pages.
function beginSearch() { ... }

function searchCompleted(results) {
  // This here is what I view as the main problem
  pageControl.showSearchResultsPage(results);
}
```

The problem is that `searcher` is specifically tied to `pageControl`, *and* it's making the decision that the search result page will be the next thing to appear. The example I was going to give to people about why this is bad gives the idea that "*You wouldn't directly conditionally call the logic for your entire app inside of Button>onClick*", but I'm trying to find a more comprehensive argument about why that is.

At first I thought this was "inversion of control" but looking that up on Wikipedia didn't portray it as negatively, so I don't think that's the right term for this kind of pattern.

Is there a name for this anti-pattern of having low-level components controlling higher-level ones?

Comment: It's called the "not everything has to have a name" pattern.

Comment: "some things are just bad"

Comment: That's simply high coupling. And between distant layers and in the wrong direction, too.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvotes? What makes this not a well-formed question?

Comment: @Katana314 the reason for the down-votes is simply that it isn't on topic for the site. As to why the questions is not well formed; it contains the presumption that the code contains a specific anti-pattern of which you don't know the name of. Maybe it is an antipattern maybe it isnt - that is likely subjective.

Comment: I don't really think this is a "primarily opinion-based" question, so I've edited it a bit to try and remove any wording that may suggest it is looking for opinions, and am voting to reopen. I also think @KilianFoth is close with the term "high coupling", or "tight coupling". A quick search on "tight coupling programming" gives you plenty of examples and explanations on why programmers try to avoid this, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2832047), although that's more about separating interfaces from implementation, and not necessary about program flow and separation of concerns.

Comment: layering violation.

Comment: "You wouldn't directly conditionally call the logic for your entire app inside of Button>onClick" - does this mean the onClick method in the Button class, or the onClick method in a particular button?

Comment: @immibis Inside the Button class. Button is meant to serve as a good example of a class that is used for various functional purposes in different classes, but does not have any explicit dependencies on them.

Comment: Someone should probably take one of their comments and post it as an answer. Doesn't even need a lot of detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called an *inversion of authority*, named so by Ed Yourdon if memory serves. An example of the usage can be found [here](http://gmitweb.gmit.ie/pdunne/sweng/08-StructuredDes.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

**Circular Dependency**

If we view pageControl.js as your UI layer, a controller perhaps, and searcher.js as you data access and or business layer, a circular dependency has been introduced that effectively makes them inseparable and defeats any benefits of layering.

Arguments could also be made for spaghetti code and accidental complexity.